# JavaScript file new version of hypeledger composer (latest)

Tags: javascript, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Hyperledger Composer, Please help me to convert in JavaScript transaction processor(file .js) in old version to new version (**latest**). I want to update my code to use new syntax.

**Here is my code (old version)**

```
function sampleTransaction(tx) {

    // Update the asset with the new value.
    tx.asset.value = tx.newValueSample;
    tx.test.value = tx.newalueTest;;

    return getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant')
          .then(function (assetParticipant) {

          })
          .then(function () {
              return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.TestAsset');
          })
          .then(function (testRegistry) {
              // Update the asset in the asset registry.
              return testRegistry.update(tx.test);
          })
          .then(function () {
              return getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset');
          })
          .then(function (assetRegistry) {
              // Update the asset in the asset registry.
              return assetRegistry.update(tx.asset);
          });
}
```

**Below, is example code in new version.**

```
async function tradeCommodity(trade) {
    trade.commodity.owner = trade.newOwner;
    let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.mynetwork.Commodity');
    await assetRegistry.update(trade.commodity);
}
```

Comment: Can you share the .cto file .

Answer (score 0):

```
async function sampleTransaction(tx) {

   // Update the asset with the new value.
   tx.asset.value = tx.newValueSample;
   tx.test.value = tx.newalueTest;

   let assetParticipant = await getParticipantRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleParticipant');
   // assetParticipant isn't used but I left it in anyway

   let testRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.TestAsset'); 
   await testRegistry.update(tx.test);
   let assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleAsset');
   await assetRegistry.update(tx.asset);
}
```